# Pasting Multiple Excel Ranges onto Body of Outlook Mail Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I'm try to make a macro that creates and sends out a report using the tables made in an excel sheet. I'm trying to paste multiple ranges into the outlook body but instead of coming one after another, all of the tables end up inside the first table. Below is the code that I made for sending out the email.

```
Sub SendEmail()
    
    Dim M As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim outlook As Object
    Dim newEmail As Object
    Dim xInspect As Object
    Dim pageEditor As Object
    Dim dt As Date
    
    'Copy range of interest
    Dim r0 As Range
    Set r0 = Range("J6:T14")
    r0.Copy

    'Open a new mail item
    'Dim outlookApp As outlook.Application
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'Dim outMail As outlook.MailItem
    Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    
    dt = Date
    
    With outMail
        .To = "****@****.com;****@****.com"
        .CC = "****@***.com"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Manhattan Case Engagement Report " & dt
        .Body = "Good Morning , " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Please find the Manhattan Case Engagement report for " & dt & " below. Please let me know if there are any issues." _
            

         outMail.Display
         
        Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
        
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        
        .htmlbody = .htmlbody & "<p><u><span style='background-color:#FF0'>Overall Metrics:</span></u></p>"
        
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        
        
        
        wordDoc.Paragraphs(4).Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
        
        Dim r1 As Range
        Set r1 = Range("J16:L22")
        r1.Copy
        
        
        .htmlbody = .htmlbody & "<p><u><span style='background-color:#FF0'>Customer Inquiries:</span></u></p>"
        
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        
        wordDoc.Paragraphs(8).Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
        
        
        .htmlbody = .htmlbody & "<p><u><span style='background-color:#FF0'>Attachment Acknowledgement:</span></u></p>"
        
        Dim r2 As Range
        Set r2 = Range("J24:O29")
        r2.Copy
        
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        
        wordDoc.Paragraphs(12).Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
        
        
        .htmlbody = .htmlbody & "<p><u><span style='background-color:#FF0'>Case Activity (Major Districts):</span></u></p>"
        
        Dim r3 As Range
        Set r3 = Range("O32:R69")
        r3.Copy
        
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        
        wordDoc.Paragraphs(16).Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
        
        
        
        .htmlbody = .htmlbody & "<p><u><span style='background-color:#FF0'>Survey Metrics:</span></u></p>"
        
        
        Dim r4 As Range
        Set r4 = Range("B72:R69")
        r4.Copy
        
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        
        wordDoc.Paragraphs(20).Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
        
        .htmlbody = .htmlbody & "<p><u><span style='background-color:#FF0'>*Blank Cells are due to inadequate information available in the start of the year</span></u></p>"
        
        Dim r5 As Range
        Set r5 = Range("B98:F114")
        r5.Copy
        
        
        .htmlbody = .htmlbody & "<p><u><span style='background-color:#FF0'>Retail 2-80 Gas(YTD)</span></u></p>"
        wordDoc.Paragraphs(4).Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
        
        Set pageEditor = Nothing
        End With
        Set outMail = Nothing
        Set newOutlook = Nothing
        
        
       
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Sub SendEmailWithRange()
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim dt As Date
    Dim X
    
    Dim r0 As Range: Set r0 = Range("J6:T14")
    Dim r1 As Range: Set r1 = Range("J16:L22")
    Dim r2 As Range: Set r2 = Range("J24:O29")
    Dim r3 As Range: Set r3 = Range("O32:R69")
    Dim r4 As Range: Set r4 = Range("B72:R69")
    Dim r5 As Range: Set r5 = Range("B98:F114")
        
    dt = Date
    
    With CreateObject("outlook.application").CreateItem(0)
        .Display 'Change to .Send to send the email immediately
        
        .Body = "Good Morning , " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Please find the Manhattan Case Engagement report for " & dt & " below. Please let me know if there are any issues." & vbCrLf
            
        Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        
        X = doc.Range.End - 1
        r0.Copy
        doc.Range(X).Paste
            
        X = doc.Range.End - 1
        doc.Range(X) = vbNewLine
                
        X = doc.Range.End - 1
        r1.Copy
        doc.Range(X).Paste
            
        X = doc.Range.End - 1
        doc.Range(X) = vbNewLine
                
        X = doc.Range.End - 1
        r2.Copy
        doc.Range(X).Paste
            
        X = doc.Range.End - 1
        doc.Range(X) = vbNewLine
                
        X = doc.Range.End - 1
        r3.Copy
        doc.Range(X).Paste
            
        X = doc.Range.End - 1
        doc.Range(X) = vbNewLine
                
        X = doc.Range.End - 1
        r4.Copy
        doc.Range(X).Paste
            
        X = doc.Range.End - 1
        doc.Range(X) = vbNewLine
                
        X = doc.Range.End - 1
        r5.Copy
        doc.Range(X).Paste
            
        X = doc.Range.End - 1
        doc.Range(X) = vbNewLine
        
        .To = "****@****.com;****@****.com"
        .CC = "****@***.com"
        .Subject = "Manhattan Case Engagement Report " & dt
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    End With
    

    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code three ways of setting the message body are used at the same time - the `Body`, `HTMLBody` and the Word object model (`WordEditor`). I'd suggest using the *single approach* of modifying the message body. In your scenario that would be the Word object model.

When you are done with `WordEditor` you can save the item to make changes permanent and then edit the item using the `HTMLBody` property if required.